# Is this an authentic photo of a parasite infection on a man's shoulder?

Tags: environmental-health

I've been forced to see an image countless times on my Facebook news feed.The picture shows this massive circle on a mans should that's bulging out and the circle has several honey comb like chambers with what appears to be a nested worm inside the middle of the honey comb cavern.

I must warn you it's not pleasant, but [here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2TCg.png).

Evidently from the little bit I've gathered there is a soap in distribution that causes or caused people(s) to get a large parasite. There isn't much detail on what this whole story or parasite is other than the line, "Retweet/Repost this before it spreads!".

I do not like medically-related topics - especially deformities like these. They just really give me goose bumps.

Can someone please shine some light on what exactly this disgusting thing is, whether or not its real, and if it is real how you know it's real?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/inboxer/scams/headshoulders.asp) already covered this one. It's a composite image of a man and a lotus seed pod.

> The static image accompanying the posts was the one displayed above, which allegedly pictures some form of bizarre injury or infection that befall a user of that brand of shampoo.
>
> The image itself is a hoax, a fabrication that imitates a notorious fake photograph of a supposed ['breast rash](http://www.snopes.com/photos/medical/breastrash.asp) caused by South American larvae' (created by merging a picture of a [lotus seed pod](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=775&q=%22lotus+seed+pod%22&oq=%22lotus+seed+pod%22&gs_l=img.3..0l10.703.4614.0.4750.22.19.3.0.0.0.151.1526.15j4.19.0....0...1ac.1.48.img..1.21.1469.ciT7t23HS88) with a picture of a human shoulder) which has been circulating on the Internet since 2003 [...]

Comment: Thank God, heaven almighty I've been going crazy and wanting to throw up.

Comment: @2g7hgfdr8324 Check out the linked breast rash article too. It seems there's a rich tradition of grossing people out by photoshopping these seedpods onto pictures of body parts.

Comment: dude I have a weak stomach even though I know it's fake I'm still incredibly grossed out.

Comment: @2g7hgfdr8324 They have a lousy imagination anyway. There are plenty of seriously disgusting things nature actually *can* do to us.

Comment: @2g7hgfdr8324: Shadur has it right. Do not, under any circumstances, do an image search for the words "ulcerating tumor"...

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt Not in a million years would I

Comment: There are also horrible things that people do to themselves. Also don't ever do a google image search for "Subincision" and for that one even the wikipedia article isn't safe.